# How to subtract two dates and covert into year

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have two classes `UserServiceH2`in which my database `CRUD` logic is encapsulated and the other is `UserController` in which i am calling the methods from `UserServiceH2`. I have the following question

> In classes UserServiceH2 and UserController implement a public int
>   getAvgMembership() that returns the average membership length in years
>   given all users (as the length take current date minus doj). For this
>   task use aggregates in HQL

```
public int getAvgMembership() {
    List<User> allUsers = getAllUsers();
    for(int i = 0; i < allUsers.size(); i++) {
        int year = allUsers.get(i).getDateOfJoining();
        //stuck here
    }
}
```

Comment: Is dateOfJoining of type `int`?

Comment: no it is of type Date of java util library.But i need to first get the difference and then return it as number of years.For example, This person is member of the company for 2 years